# std::call_once and memory reordering

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-fences

Given the code from [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-6-double-checked-locking.html):

```
class lazy_init
{
    mutable std::once_flag flag;
    mutable std::unique_ptr<expensive_data> data;

    void do_init() const
    {
        data.reset(new expensive_data);
    }
public:
    expensive_data const& get_data() const
    {
        std::call_once(flag,&lazy_init::do_init,this);
        return *data;
    }
};
```

And I saw a few variants of the same pattern elsewhere also. So my question is: why this code is considered save? and why compiler can't just read *data* before calling std::call_once and ends up with an incorrect data?
e.g

```
tmp = data.get();
std::call_once(flag,&lazy_init::do_init,this);
return *tmp;
```

I mean I have found nothing about any barriers which would prevent that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Programming in C++ would be essentially impossible if the compiler was allowed to produce code that matched what you describe.

This is stated in §1.9/14 *Program Execution* (n3290):

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value
>   computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

Your `return` statement is sequenced after the preceding full expression. The compiler has to output code *as if* all side-effects of that preceding statement has been completely evaluated before it evaluates the return statement.
Your example doesn't respect that rule, since it evaluates `*data` before taking into account the side-effects of the `std::call_once(...)` full expression.

Additionally, `std::call_once` has this in its description (§30.4.4.2/2 and 3):

> 2/ *Effects*: An execution of call_once that does not call its func is a passive execution. An execution of call_once that calls its func is an active execution. An active execution shall call `INVOKE (DECAY_-
>   COPY ( std::forward<Callable>(func)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)`. If such
>   a call to func throws an exception the execution is exceptional, otherwise it is returning. An exceptional execution shall propagate the exception to the caller of call_once. Among all executions of call_once for any given once_flag: at most one shall be a returning execution; if there is a returning execution, it shall be the last active execution; and there are passive executions only if there is a returning execution. [ **Note: passive executions allow other threads to reliably observe the results produced by the earlier returning execution. — end note** ]
>
> 3/ *Synchronization*: For any given once_flag: all active executions occur in a total order; completion of an active execution synchronizes with the start of the next one in this total order; and the returning execution synchronizes with the return from all passive executions.

So the standard mandates synchronization to fit your use-case.

Comment: Well, you are right my example just breaks sequential execution. But let's try another one: first thread execute call_once and set once_flag. It is guaranteed by the standard that other threads can't execute until flag is set(call is done). But I found nothing about guarantee that data changed in that call should be correctly seen by other threads. So I suppose that datachanges could be seen, at the moment, only by Thread 1since it contains it in its cache. Thread 2 sees that flag is set and continues execution. It reads incorrect data and we have UB.

Comment: Or there is some kind of guarantee that it can't happen? I'm totally new to those barriers and I'm cracked my mind about it.

Comment: The standard mandates synchronization for `call_once`, it is pretty much designed for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Mat, I've read this description many times and just ignored that note :)